# Pixelate image object in R

Tags: r, image, processing, pixel

How do you [pixelate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixelation) an image object in R? In other words, how do you transform a high-quality image object to a lower-bit (for example 8 pixels) image object?

I have started using "EBimage" package for image processing, yet couldn't find a function that can do this. Any ideas? We can use below example to talk on.

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage",dependencies=T)
require("EBImage")

link1 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/algons/coursera/master/junk_pic.png"
#Download images and create img objects
download.file(link1, "img1.jpg", mode="wb", quiet=TRUE)
img1 <- readImage("img1.jpg")
```

Comment: Do you mean a pixelated image (where the pixels are so big as to be blocky) or a posterised image (where there are very few unique colours)?

Comment: I might be missing the naming convention, but I think it's pixelation.

The issue is that I want to match two "almost equal" images (the same images but one of them is higher quality - naked eye doesn't notice it, but it affects the image values). I am hypothesizing that if I pixelate both images to small number of pixels, they'll have the same image values.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the comparison of two images is the whole of your application, or just an incidental part you happen to need to do in order to get on with something else. If it is the latter, ImageMagick is very capable for this - see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Supposing you have two different sized images (`a.jpg` and `b.jpg`), you can force copies of them both to 100x100 pixels (say) and then compare the root mean square difference between the pixels like this:

```
convert a.jpg -resize 100x100! 1.jpg
convert b.jpg -resize 100x100! 2.jpg
compare 1.jpg 2.jpg -metric rmse null:
```

and it will give you a root mean square difference as its numerical output, with `0` meaning images are identical.

You can shell out from R and do the above with the `system()` command

```
system("compare 1.jpg 2.jpg -metric rmse null:",intern=TRUE);
```

Or you can convert the images to say, 4x4, and do the vector comparison yourself:

```
convert a.jpg -resize 4x4! smallA.jpg
convert b.jpg -resize 4x4! smallB.jpg
```